# ¿Cómo acceder a un valor de un array asociativo dentro de otro?

Tags: php

Tengo este código de PHP y a la hora de recorrer los arrays la información se muestra bien, pero no consigo acceder a un dato concreto que quiera buscar.

```
<?php
$nombre = "E";
$numeroEmpresa = 0;
$i = 0;

while ($i <= 35) {
    $Ibex35 = array($nombre . $numeroEmpresa => array(
        "Precio" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(%)" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(euros)" => rand(),
        "VOLUMEN" => rand()
    ));
    $i++;
    $numeroEmpresa++;
    var_dump($Ibex35);
}
```

Por ejemplo, si quiero acceder al valor del índice "Precio" de la empresa "E1", ¿Cómo debería hacer? Si hago esto no funciona:

```
echo "Imprime el valor que tu quieras <br>";
echo $Ibex35["E1"]["Precio"];
?>
```

Gracias.

Comment: puedes aclarar el numero de empresa de que numero a que numero debe ir??? de 0 a 35, de 1 a 36 ???

Comment: Sí, el número de empresas tiene que ir de 1 a 35. La idea es que en un futuro pueda ir añadiendo empresas con cada uno de sus valores al array e ir actualizando y mostrando los datos "a tiempo real", como si fuesen valores de un mercado bursátil, por ejemplo.

Comment: aquí te dejo lo que fue mi respuesta; saludos: [enlace](https://gist.github.com/arcanisgk/1ee76878fde51963d51e8d73c4b0b58d)

Comment: me indicas si puedes ver el gist si necesitas mas ayuda puedes contactarme por Discord: ArcanisGK507#6629

Comment: @Francisco Núñez-Todo Poderoso Sí, lo he visualizado ya y lo tengo descargado. Muchas gracias  :) Aunque con mi código inicial sigo sin poder acceder al valor $Ibex35["E1"]["Precio"]; Sí puedo acceder al $Ibex35["E35"]["Precio"];, pero ni aun declarando el array final fuera del bucle: $Ibex35=array(); se me almacena la empresa1. Tengo que ver en qué fallo, porque con vuestro código está todo OK ;)

Comment: De nada es un placer enseñarle o apoyar a todos los que tengan dudas, puedes tambien marcar como respuesta cualquiera de las publicaciones o la que de estas se adapte mejor a tu desarrollo. me parecen validas las dos que quedan.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso voto para que reabras tu respuesta, estaba demasiado buena

Answer (score 2):

Depende del momento en el que estás ingresando a dicho valor.
Con el código como lo tienes, el for asigna en cada vuelta nuevamente los valores, es decir, no tienes desde el E0 al E35, solo queda el E35.

Si quisieras meter desde el E1 al E35, debes agregarlos al array para poder obtenerlos.

```
<?php
$nombre = "E";
$numeroEmpresa = 0;
$i = 0;

while ($i <= 35) {
    // Acá estás reasignando el valor nuevamente.
    $Ibex35 = array($nombre . $numeroEmpresa => array(
        "Precio" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(%)" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(euros)" => rand(),
        "VOLUMEN" => rand()
    ));

    $i++;
    $numeroEmpresa++;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($Ibex35);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($Ibex35["E35"]["Precio"]);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es incorrecto estas sobre escribiendo la variable `$Ibex35` al final tendrías solo el ultimo valor que asigno el while y no los 34 primeros.

Comment: Pero eso es lo que dije, `Con el código como lo tienes, el for asigna en cada vuelta nuevamente los valores`

Comment: me gusta mas usar la opción que usa range XD

Comment: Con ese código mío sigo sin poder meter desde el E1 al E35 en el array para luego así poder acceder a cualquiera de los valores de forma individual. ¿Qué tendría que hacer para lograrlo con ese código con el que empecé? Gracias.

Comment: Como muestran en otras respuestas, y como mencioné acá, debes crear la variable fuera del for, para poder asignar todos los valores que quieres.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas mal hechas en tu código:

1. Estás declarando el array final dentro del bucle. Si lo que quieres es llenar un array de empresas decláralo vacío fuera del bucle y luego lo vas llenando.
2. Estás creando una estructura más compleja de lo que necesitas y por eso no funciona. Simplemente, da a cada array la clave `E` + el valor de `i`  y crea un sub-array con los demás valores.
3. Estás declarando variables de forma redundante. Si aumentas `$i` desde el principio la puedes usar combinada con `$nombre`, prescindiendo así de `$numeroEmpresa`. Para esto tendrás que recurrir a un pequeño *trick* que consistirá en dejar el `while` en `34` (de lo contrario te creará 36 empresas). O, si quieres, puedes declaras `$i=1` inicialmente y poner el `$i++` al final. Eso depende de si no necesitas a `$i` para otra cosa en tu código y ésta debe valer `0` sí o sí.

El código quedaría así:

```
$nombre = "E";
$i = 0;

$Ibex35=array();

while ($i <= 34) {
    $i++;
    $Ibex35 ["$nombre$i"]=  array(
        "Precio" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(%)" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(euros)" => rand(),
        "VOLUMEN" => rand()
    );
}  

echo $Ibex35["E1"]["Precio"];
```

**Salida:**

```
734146980    # El ramdon que se haya asignado
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y por la corrección, con gente así da gusto aprender :)

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso mi intención no era que borraras tu respuesta. Lamento que te hayas tomado tan a mal una simple crítica.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso a mí me resultaba interesante la respuesta! Quería echar un vistazo. Aprovecho para preguntaros, eso sí, una cosa: ¿Con el código inicial que yo he puesto (array asociativo dentro de array asociativo) habría alguna manera de acceder a un valor concreto (ejemplo: $Ibex35["E1"]["Precio"];) como se hace en vuestras correcciones? Gracias.

Comment: pensé que las respuestas eran para la comunidad, no para alguien en particular... y si la borre por que no tiene sentido una respuesta llena de comentarios absurdos. que no ayuda en nada a mejorarla... el cual es el objetivo de los comentarios...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso acabas de leer que OP encuentra tu respuesta interesante. Sugiero que la recuperes y borremos los comentarios, dando esto por zanjado.

Comment: @Serzox si se puede solo debes navegar a través de los nodos del array o objeto ya te envié el link del gist, en la ultima forma de hacerlo que consideran que es un tráiler para recoger cartas, te agregue como convertirlo en un objeto y eso te permite extraer el valor de la propiedad que s lo mismo que pides: esto `$Ibex35["E1"] ["Precio"];` es esto: `$Ibex35->E1->Precio;` si lo casteas con `json`

Comment: @Serzox la clave para acceder a un array de cualquier nivel es seguir una estructura conforme a la realidad del array. Si tienes un array con una clave `E1` y dentro de él otro array con un índice `0` por ejemplo, accedes así: `$array["E1"][0]["Precio"]`  y si fuera un array con clave nominal: `$array["E1"]["E1a"]["Precio"]` Se trata simplemente de seguir la estructura que tenga tu array.

Answer (score 0):

***Primero:***
para lograr esa estructura tu variable debe ser un array antes de iniciar la asignación de datos entonces te falta esto, la declaración:

```
$Ibex35=[];
```

También es importante que comprender que la variable `$numeroEmpresa` debe ser inicializada en 1 ya que no me confirmaste en los comentario como es la estructura numérica, en mi ejemplo iría de la empresa #1 a la #35.

entonces yo usaría los siguiente:

```
<?php

$nombre="E";
$numeroEmpresa=1;
$i=0;   
$Ibex35 = [];  //te falta esto

while ($i<35) {
    $i++;
    $Ibex35[$nombre.$numeroEmpresa] = [
        "Precio" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(%)" => rand(),
        "VARIACION(euros)" => rand(),
        "VOLUMEN" => rand(),
    ];
    $numeroEmpresa++;
};

echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35['E35'], true);
echo "</pre>";

/**
 * o si tienes los datos en variables puedes hacer esto:
*/

$num=35;

echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35['E'.$num]['Precio'], true);
echo "</pre>";

/**
 * y si imprimes la variable completa veras que tendras todos los datos:
*/

echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35, true);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Output #1 y 2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Output #3:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***El siguiente nivel, emplea una funcion:*** con esta buena practica tu código es funcional y mantenible, no requiere usar de variables ni contadores.

```
<?php

function get_values(){
    return [
        'Precio' => rand(),
        'VARIACION(%)' => rand(),
        'VARIACION(euros)' => rand(),
        'VOLUMEN' => rand(),
    ];
}


$prefix="E";
$range=range(1,35); 
$Ibex35 = [];
foreach($range as $key){
    $Ibex35[$prefix.$key]=get_values();
}


echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35['E35'], true);
echo "</pre>";
```

***El siguiente nivel: implementando: `array_map`, `array_walk` y `array_flip`***

```
<?php

function updateIndex(&$element, $clave, $prefijo){
    $element = $prefijo.$element;
}

function get_values(&$element, $clave){
    $properties =  ['Precio'=>0,'VARIACION(%)'=>0,'VARIACION(euros)'=>0,'VOLUMEN'=>0];
    //mapeamos las propiedades y les asignamos un valor rand()
    $element =  array_map(function() {
        return rand();
    },$properties);
}

$prefix='E';
$Ibex35=range(1,35);
array_walk($Ibex35,'updateIndex',$prefix); //agregamos el prefijo
$Ibex35=array_flip($Ibex35); //invertimos los datos.
array_walk($Ibex35,'get_values'); //insertamos las propiedades.


echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35, true);
echo "</pre>";
```

para esta ultima opción el resultado es el mismo que el output 1, 2 y 3.

***Versión con resultado y acceso OOP***

También para concluir sobre la forma de acceder a datos en un array se suele usar el casteo a objeto mayormente visto en la programación orientada a objeto (OOP):

```
<?php

function updateIndex(&$element, $clave, $prefijo){
    $element = $prefijo.$element;
}

function get_values(&$element, $clave){
    $properties =  ['Precio'=>0,'VARIACION(%)'=>0,'VARIACION(euros)'=>0,'VOLUMEN'=>0];
    $element = array_map(function() {
        return rand();
    },$properties);
}

$prefix='E';
$Ibex35=range(1,35);
array_walk($Ibex35,'updateIndex',$prefix); //agregamos el prefijo
$Ibex35=array_flip($Ibex35); //invertimos los datos.
array_walk($Ibex35,'get_values');
//con json_encode casteamos el array a un string.
//luego con json_decode casteamos el string en un objeto.
$Ibex35=json_decode(json_encode($Ibex35)); 

echo "<pre>";
echo var_export($Ibex35->E1->Precio); //acceso al dato como propiedad.
echo "</pre>";
```

*Espero mi respuesta solucione tu duda y amplié tus conocimiento en el manejo  de array.*

***Documentación asociada:***

[Crear Array Multidimensional con loop while.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11663331/4717133)
[Ejecute la función PHP en While Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427764/4717133)
[Uso de variables por Referencia `&$foo`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.php)
[Método de php: `array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)
[Método de php: `array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php)
[Método de php: `array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-flip.php)
[Castear Array a Un String type JSON con `json-encode`.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)
[Castear String type JSON a un Objeto con `json-decode`.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Francisco!!! Voy a ir probando todo lo que me comentas. He empezado ahora con el tema de arrays en PHP y todavía no tengo mucha soltura. Gracias por tus soluciones y consejos :)

Comment: @Serzox no te preocupes para eso estamos. cualquier duda me dejas en comentarios para ayudarte.